# Any tutorial for onenote api integration for cross platform mobile app dev using Flex builder?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder, onenote

I tried to google but could not find any tutorial which can give a head start on using [MS Onenote api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575420%28v=office.15%29.aspx) with Flex builder 4.6. Can anybody help me get started by pointing to a online tutorial or any other solution is also welcome. I have an existing app for android and IOS but also need new feature added in the same app.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any sample projects for Flex Builder. We only have samples for iOS, Android, Windows and Windows Phone for now. We will be adding PHP, Ruby and Node.js samples soon.

You can find the samples here: https://github.com/orgs/OneNoteDev/

-- James ([@jmslau](https://twitter.com/jmslau))

Comment: James, In the above referenced answer, I can find no "Windows", I can find a Windows Store, Windows Phone.  Is there a simple Hello World example for a Windows 8.1 Desktops/ Windows Forms example.